# How do you append the contents of one file to several files in a loop in Python?

Tags: python, loops, file, io

I am trying to append the contents of a markdown file to several markdown files in sub-directories. The directory structure is like follows:

```
projects
   |
   |-project1
        |- README.md
        |- other files, directories
   |-project2
        |- README.md
        |- other files, directories
   |-project3
        |- other files, directories
```

The file `append.md` should be appended to the end of the `README.md` file in any project directories that have `README.md`.

My current code is as follows:

```py
import os

appendFile = open('.\\append.md')

for project, dirs, filenames in os.walk('.'):
  for filename in filenames:
    if filename == 'README.md' and project != '.':
      print(f'Current Project is {project}.')
      readme = os.path.join(project, filename)
      print(f'Current README is {readme}.')
      with open(readme, 'a') as file:
        file.write(appendFile.read())
        # file.flush()
        # os.fsync(file.fileno())

appendFile.close()
```

`append.md` and this script lives under the root `projects` folder. The print statements confirm that I am hitting each `project` folder and finding each of the READMEs. The `file.write(append.read())` works for the first project but then doesn't work for any subsequent projects. No errors are thrown; it just fails to write. I've tried adding `file.flush()` followed by `os.fsync(file.fileno())` but nothing changes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Calling `.read()` will return the contents of the file but subsequent calls will not return anything because the file buffer/stream has been consumed. Save the result of `appendFile.read()` to a variable and write that instead

Comment: Read append only once to var, and write it to files from this var

Comment: Yup, that was it. Seems obvious now. Thanks @IainShelvington